# Make doctrine return databasefields as keys for returned data

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm retrieving data from a Mysql database, and this is done via mapping my entity properties to database fields using Doctrine with annotations as shown in this 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzcjh.png). Retrieving the data is not the problem, but my property name is used as key for the returned data, which is not what i want.

**Example**:

I have a property gridId (camelCase), which is mapped to a database field called grid_id (snake_case) as shown in the image above. The key for the rows returned for this property will be gridId, and not grid_id, which is desired in my case.

An example of the current situation:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13lFd.png).

The desired situation:

```
$grid = 
[
    grid_block_id = 18

    width = 50

    width_pixels = 50
]
```

Changing either the database fields or the property names is not an option in my case.

**EDIT**

I'm using JMS as serializer. I guess the 4th option of [@Jakumi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56074152/8993284)'s answer is probably the best option for my use case. Somehow use the serializer to return the property's column name as key for returned values.

My struggle when retrieving data from doctrine is that i have to manually adjust the keys fetched by doctrine as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBE57.png) as this is how the front-end expects it to be.

Comment: What serializer are you using?

Comment: please add some code of how you're going to use this ... (@KamilAdryjanek I think none. looks like phpstorm or something)

Comment: I can see `@Serializer\Expose` so I assume there is some serializer

Comment: you're right. sry.

Comment: https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations see @SerializedName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what you're saying is ... you want to actively ignore the object relational mapping (ORM) that the doctrine ORM you're using is providing you and which actually provide the keys exactly the way your entity names them?

I assume there is some good (or not so good) reason for this. Depending on your use case, different solutions may be the best. Options including (but probably very incomplete):

#### option 1: add a function to the entity

```
class Grid {
    /** all your fields **/

    public function toArray() {
        return [
            'grid_id' => $this->gridId,
            // ...
        ];
    }
}
```

#### option 2: don't use the orm

add a function in your `GridRepository` like:

```
function getRawAll() {
    $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    $_result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM grid');
    $results = [];
    while($row = $_result->fetch()) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }

    return $results;
}
```

and similar. Those are obviously circumventing the ORM. The ORM is for retrieving objects, and those have specified fields.

#### option 3: return the given array back to the unmapped state

use the `EntityManager`'s [`getClassMetadata`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.html#method_getClassMetadata) ([`ClassMetadataInfo`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.html)->fieldMapping) to fetch the mapping for your fields, and "revert" the renaming.

This is probably *slightly* better than option 1 to *some* degree, since it doesn't have to be updated.

#### option 4: use a serializer that does your property name translation.

since you're apparently already using the [jms serializer](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations), the SerializedName annotation can probably help, although the default appears to be snake case, but maybe somewhere it's overridden? you might want to check your configuration ...

Comment: Reverting the renaming is exactly what i'm looking for, could you please elaborate how i could accomplish this? In the ClassMetadataInfo->fieldMapping resides my columnName, which is what i want instead of my propertyName.

Comment: @Rummens imho option 1 or option 4 is probably the best solution in your case. but it really depends on how you intend to use your "unmapped" data. please append that information to your question.

Comment: I ended up using the JMS serializer to re-convert my property names, though not the best solution performance wise, it'll suffice for now. Therefore marking your answer as accepted.